# Change layout of post depending on category

Tags: posts, categories

I am having two kinds of categories one is `events` and another is `no_category`. Posts of [Event Calendar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-calendar-3-for-php-53/) are placed under `events` category and rest are in `no_category`.

As you know what is the default layout of all the posts. At the top Title of the post then below it reply then below it's content etc...

Now I want to change the format for "event" category posts as in Excel format:

```
Title | Created Date | Created By | Details | Edit
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Conditional Tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Category_Page) [`in_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/in_category) within the loop:

```
if( in_category( 'events' ) ):
    // output stuff for events category post
else:
    // not in events category
endif;
```

Another option for single posts is to [load a different template with a filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Filter_Hierarchy) based on the category:

```
function wpa8176_category_single_template( $template = '' ){
    $categories = get_the_category();
    foreach( $categories as $cat ):
        if( 'events' == $cat->name ):
            $template = locate_template( array( "events-single.php", $template ), false );
        endif;
    endforeach;
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'wpa8176_category_single_template' );
```

Comment: Kindly tell me in which file I have to do this (in_category).

Comment: In whatever template file is outputting your posts. See the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) to figure out which one.

Comment: Actually **events** posts are coming from any of the plugin php file so I am not able from where to do theses changes

Comment: you'll have to ask the plugin developer then, or perhaps someone else here is familiar with the plugin and can answer your question.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Mr. Milo I will try it myself if I need more help then Please HELP me!